# In ant, how does one create and use a 'library' of targets?

Tags: ant

To eliminate redundancy in my ant `build.xml` files, I decided out-factor the repeated targets into `mytargets.xml` file, publish it to to the artifact repository, and then import it in the following way:

```
<import>
    <url url="http://mycompany.com/artifacts/mycompany.com/mytargets/1.2.3/mytargets-1.2.3.xml"/>
</import>
```

There are two things I *don't* like about this approach:

1. `mytargets-1.2.3.xml` never appears anywhere on the disk where I can easily look at it.
2. I absolutely need access to http://mycompany.com/artifacts in order to do *anything* in the project---it completely undermines offline work.

So, I tried creating a `setup` target to fetch a local copy of `mytargets.xml` and adjusted my `<import>` to use this local copy.

```
<import file="${basedir}/antlib/mytargets/mytargets.xml"/>
```

However, as you have probably guessed, I cannot even execute my `setup` my target after adjusting my `<import>` in this way because the file does not yet exist:

```
Buildfile: /home/me/myproject/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/me/myproject/build.xml:265: Cannot find /home/me/myproject/antlib/mytargets/mytargets.xml imported from /home/me/myproject/build.xml
```

Adding `optional="true"` to the `<import>` only defers the problem to the first target that depends upon `mytargets.xml`.

I looked at https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html, but this approach does not appears to permit you to define a `<target>`.

So, how does someone share bits of ant XML across multiple projects?  Am I already doing it the 'one true way'?  Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Looks like you "just don't do this"...

Answer (score 0):

If you're mainly just trying to avoid download the remote copy when you have a local copy already available, you can try something like this:

```
<condition property="mytargets.xml.available">
    <available file="${basedir}/antlib/mytargets/mytargets.xml" />
</condition>

<target name="setup" unless="mytargets.xml.available">
    <get
        src="http://mycompany.com/artifacts/mycompany.com/mytargets/1.2.3/mytargets-1.2.3.xml"
        dest="${basedir}/antlib/mytargets"
    />
</target>

<target name="main" depends="setup">
    <import file="${basedir}/antlib/mytargets/mytargets.xml" />

    ...
</target>
```

Comment: No, it's actually a chicken-egg problem with downloading the file and importing it.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems to me that `<target>` is inherently local and not intended for reuse.  On the other hand, `<macrodef>` appears intended for reuse.

Here is the 'library', `mymacros.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<antlib>
    <macrodef name="mymacro">
        ...
    </macrodef>
</antlib>
```

Here is the client, `myproject/build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="myproject">
    <target name="mytarget">
        <mymacro/>
    </target>
    <taskdef file="mymacros.xml"/>
</project>
```

Unlike `<import>` and `<include>`, `<taskdef>` will not cause the build to fail immediately if `mymacros.xml` is missing, which gives you the opportunity to download it.